# EF Core - What are the default isolation levels for context.SaveChanges() and context.Database.BeginTransation()?

Tags: entity-framework-core, isolation-level

I've read here https://coderwall.com/p/jnniww/why-you-shouldn-t-use-entity-framework-with-transactions that Database.BeginTransaction() uses serializable by default, but I can't confirm this anywhere else.

Comment: It is `IsolationLevel.Unspecified`, which means the actual default is provided by the corresponding ADO.NET provider. For SqlServer it is `ReadCommitted`.